# Easiest way to make razor intellisense update itself after changes

Tags: c#, razor, intellisense

When a razor file is open, the intellisense often fails keeps up with changes that have been made since it was open. You have to close and re-open the file before intellisense will catch up. This is especially true when it comes to things like editing the web.config in ways that will affect razor intellisense.

What's the superduperest fastest and easiest way to make razor intellisense catch up with the changes you've made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so glad you asked!

While viewing the razor file, you can use the keyboard combination Ctrl-F4 to close the file followed by Ctrl-(minus sign) which moves the cursor to the previous location thus opening the page back up for you and putting you back wherever you were in the file.